# DynamoDB 'Type DynamoDBEntry is unsupported'

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to map from one type to it's Dynamo equivalent. I want to store a list ob objects within the Dyanmo object so I'm converting it's child objects to Dynamo Documents. However, when I try to update Dynamo with the new type, it's giving me this error:

> Type Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBEntry is unsupported, it cannot be instantiated

Here is my model:

```
public class TourDetail
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string TourId { get; set; }
    public DynamoDBList Itinerary { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my AutoMapper code:

```
public DynamoModelMapper()
{
    CreateMap<TourDetail, Models.Dynamo.TourDetail>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Itinerary, x => x.MapFrom(y => convertItinerary(y.Itinerary)));
}

private List<Document> convertItinerary(IEnumerable<TourItineraryDay> itineraryDays)
{
    var docList = new List<Document>();

    foreach (var itineraryDay in itineraryDays)
    {
        var doc = new Document();
        doc.Add("day", itineraryDay.Day);
        doc.Add("title", itineraryDay.Title);
        doc.Add("description", itineraryDay.Description);
        docList.Add(doc);
    }

    return docList;
}
```

Comment: I have now ruled out AutoMapper as the issue by manually converting one object to another. Same error.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: It turned out that I shouldn't have been using DynamoDBList/Document as I was not using the Document model. I could simply use a `List<TourItineraryDay>` as Dynamo would figure it out for itself. I changed the `Itinerary` property in my `TourDetail` model to type `List<TourItineraryDay>` and removed the explicit automapper mapping for that member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I am mixing the Dynamo Data Model and the Document Model in my example. When using the Data Model, you do not need to worry about converting your collections to Dynamo-specific types like `DynamoDBList` or `List<Document>`. These types are part of the Document model and are not necessary with the Data Model.

The solution was to just change the `Itinerary` property in my `TourDetail` model to type `List<TourItineraryDay>` and removed the explicit Automapper mapping for that member.

```
public class TourDetail
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string TourId { get; set; }
    public List<TourItineraryDay> Itinerary { get; set; }
}
```